# error in publish blazor-wams version.net5 after install visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net-5, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022

I'm having a weird issue with publishing my Blazor WASM version .net5 project to IIS Service after I install my Visual Studio 2022

`In Console Write This Error : Unhandled exception rendering component: The provided expression contains a PropertyExpression which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object. System.ArgumentException: The provided expression contains a PropertyExpression which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object.`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in the same conditions.
**Is someone have been able to find a solution?**

I have to publish from an old station which is the only one that have not been upgraded to VS 2022.
This is crazy.. they have not made any regression testing to be sure that we can  publish a .net 5 app from a VS 2022?
I have 2 hosting IIS that got this error when I publish. On one of my hosting company this is OK though.  Very weird.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31546661)